# How to get list of associated objects through Foreign key table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I've got `Nodes` that have a `List<Node>` of children `Nodes`.  Following JPA conventions I end up with the following tables:

`t_node`has the attributes `id`, `name`, and `department`

`t_node_t_node` has the attributes `t_node_id` and `childNodes_id`

I want to return a list of a parent node's children nodes.  How do I write the `entitymanager` query to do so?

The closest I've gotten is:

```
List<Node> childNodes = (List<Node>) entityManager.createQuery("select n from Node n JOIN n.t_node_t_node t where n.id = " + parent_id).getResultList();
```

which returns the exception: `Could not resolve property t_node_t_node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database column `t_node_t_node` cannot be used in JPQL query. JPQL queries operate to entities and their persistent attributes, not with the database tables and columns.

Likely your entity is roughly as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Node {
    @Id private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Node parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Node> nodes;
...
}
```

When id of parent is given, child nodes can be queries as follows:

```
Long parentId = 1L;
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Node n WHERE n.parent.id =  :parentId");
q.setParameter("parentId", parentId);
List<Node> childNodes = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I updated my Node object with `@ManyToOne Node parent;` and added `(mappedBy = "parent")`.  When I create the DB now, my `t_node_t_node` table is not created.  I've implemented everything else and I'm getting a null pointer for the `childNodes` list.  I don't see any way they're associated now.

Comment: I assumed child can have only one parent. When that is the case, then there is one-to-many/many-to-one, which is then materialized to database table as an additional column. If one child can have multiple parents, then @ManyToMany can be used (and consequently there will be join table).